# how to have values in pivoted columns of spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pivot

i have dataframe with values

```
+---+-----------------------+----------+---------+------------+---------+
|id |database_name          |users     |groups   |type        |isAllowed|
+---+-----------------------+----------+---------+------------+---------+
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[hive]    |[hrhs]   |select      |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |select      |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |update      |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |create      |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |drop        |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |alter       |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |index       |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |lock        |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |all         |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |read        |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |write       |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |repladmin   |true     |
|73 |[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |serviceadmin|true     |
|84 |[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[svc02001]|[]       |select      |true     |
|84 |[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[svc02001]|[]       |update      |true     |
|84 |[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[svc02001]|[]       |create      |true     |
|84 |[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[svc02001]|[]       |drop        |true     |
|84 |[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[svc02001]|[]       |alter       |true     |
|84 |[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[svc02001]|[]       |all         |true     |
|84 |[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[svc02001]|[]       |read        |true     |
|84 |[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[svc02001]|[]       |write       |true     |
|84 |[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[]        |[walmart]|select      |true     |
|84 |[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[]        |[walmart]|read        |true     |
+---+-----------------------+----------+---------+------------+---------+
```

I want to pivot my dataframe based on type column.
so that resultant dataframe that i need is like

```
id db_name                 users    group select update create  drop  alter
73 ww_hr_dl_highsecure     hive     hrhs   true    null    null  null  null
73 ww_hr_dl_highsecure     svchrdat null   true    true    true  true  true
84 ww_core_dim_dl_tables   svc02001 true   true    true    true  true  true
```

I dont know how to have the values in the new columns that i have pivoted as values from column isAllowed in original dataframe.

what I have done till now is

```
val dfs3 = dfs2.groupBy("database_name","users").pivot("type").expr("isAllowed")
```

Comment: Maybe try replacing `expr("isAllowed")` with `agg(first($"isAllowed"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Would adding groups to the groupBy be an acceptable result ?

```
df.groupBy("database_name","users","groups").pivot("type").agg(first("isAllowed")).show(false)
```

Output :

```
+-----------------------+----------+---------+----+-----+------+----+-----+----+----+---------+------+------------+------+-----+
|database_name          |users     |groups   |all |alter|create|drop|index|lock|read|repladmin|select|serviceadmin|update|write|
+-----------------------+----------+---------+----+-----+------+----+-----+----+----+---------+------+------------+------+-----+
|[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[svc02001]|[]       |true|true |true  |true|null |null|true|null     |true  |null        |true  |true |
|[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[svchrdat]|[]       |true|true |true  |true|true |true|true|true     |true  |true        |true  |true |
|[ww_hr_dl_highsecure]  |[hive]    |[hrhe]   |null|null |null  |null|null |null|null|null     |true  |null        |null  |null |
|[ww_core_dim_dl_tables]|[]        |[walmart]|null|null |null  |null|null |null|true|null     |true  |null        |null  |null |
+-----------------------+----------+---------+----+-----+------+----+-----+----+----+---------+------+------------+------+-----+
```